# Endless "npm run eject" loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It asks me to remove or commit the untracked files but the files cannot be committed and each time I "npm run eject" I get more untracked files that start with "cache".
Please help me. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKcuQ.png)

Comment: `git commit -am 'enter a usefull description'`, or you maybe wanna add .config folder to gitignore

Comment: Still same problem and the files that cannot be commited have unrelated names like skype and screenshots